# how to make my for loop continue after using a reset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just need some guidance. I feel a bit lost with why my for loop stopped. it's a simple etch-a-sketch game, the for loop before the reset responds but after creating new grids, it doesn't load anymore. My knowledge is lacking on what I can do next. I would love some guidance, if you do fix the code please offer me an explanation or some resource that I can refer so I can understand myself.

Here is my code:

```js
//first div
let container = document.createElement('div')
container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
container.classList.add("grid");
document.body.appendChild(container);



//second div

let containerGrid = document.createElement('div')
containerGrid.setAttribute('id', 'containerGrid');
containerGrid.classList.add("grids");
document.body.appendChild(containerGrid);

//button div
let buttonDiv = document.createElement('div')
buttonDiv.setAttribute('id', 'button');
buttonDiv.classList.add("button");
document.body.appendChild(buttonDiv);

//buttons
const startAgain = document.createElement('button');
startAgain.setAttribute('id', 'createbtn');
startAgain.style.padding = "10px";
startAgain.textContent ="New grid"

container.appendChild(startAgain);

//onclick events
const resetbtn = document.getElementById("resetDivs");
resetbtn.onclick = () => resetGrid()

createbtn.onclick = () => makeCols(); 
console.log(resetbtn);



//hover color event

function random (number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (number +1));
}

function rainbowColor (e) {
    const rndCol= 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) +',' + random(255) + ')';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = rndCol;
}

//grid function
function resetGrid () {
    containerGrid.innerHTML =""
    }

//make grid 16*16

function makeCols (col) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 16*16; i++) {
        const colDivs = document.createElement('div');
        colDivs.setAttribute('id', 'col-row');
        colDivs.classList.add('cols');
        colDivs.textContent ="";
        colDivs.style.border = ('solid');
        colDivs.style.display= ('grid');
        colDivs.style.padding = ('5px');
        containerGrid.appendChild(colDivs);
    }
}
makeCols (16);


let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.cols');
for(let k=0; k<inputs.length; k++) {
    inputs[k].onclick = rainbowColor;}
let resets = document.querySelectorAll('.cols');
for(let p=0; p<inputs.length; p++) {
        inputs[p].onmouseover = rainbowColor;
}
```

```css
.grid {

width:500px;

}

.grids {

    display: grid;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows:repeat(16,1fr);
    padding: 50px 50px;
    margin-left:150px;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
 }

.rows {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    grid-column-gap:10px;
   

}
.cols {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    color:black;
}

.palette.cols:hover {
   background-color:'black'; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id ="color-picker" class = "palette">
        <input type="color" name="Rainbow" id="rainbow-colors" value= "#e66465">
        <label for="Rainbow">Rainbow</label>
    </div>
        
    <div id = "black-pick" class = "black-color">
        <input type="color" name="Black" id="black-color" value="#rrggbb">
        <label for="Black">Black</label>
    </div>

    <div id ="resetDivs" class= "btnReset">

    <input type="button" value="Reset">
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function `resetGrid()` should call `makeCols()` after it clears `containerGrid.innerHTML` to recreate the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you only draw the grid when you call `makeCols` (which I renamed to `makeGrid`, since that's a more accurate description). If you don't call the function inside the button event listener, you'll never redraw the grid.

I'm not exactly sure what the intended behaviour is supposed to be, but I'm guessing you're trying to have the `Reset` button get rid of all the colours? So I changed it to just one button that clears the grid when you click it.

I also changed the way you reset the grid. I don't think it's the best idea to just set the `innerHTML` to `""` because that only removes the grid from the HTML. But in JS, it doesn't remove the data (e.g. the event listeners) from memory!

So the way I implemented it, the grid is only drawn once. When you press `Reset`, it just changes the `background-color` of all the boxes to white.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="color-picker" class="palette">
            <input type="color" name="rainbow" id="rainbow" value="#e66465">
            <label for="rainbow">Rainbow</label>
        </div>

        <div id="black-pick" class="black-color">
            <input type="color" name="black" id="black" value="#000000">
            <label for="black">Black</label>
        </div>

        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        <br>

        <div id="container-grid" class="container"></div>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
    padding: 50px 50px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}


.box {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    color: black;
    border: solid;
    padding: 5px;
}


button {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

## javascript

```
/* first, we draw the grid */

const containerGrid = document.getElementById("container-grid");

function makeGrid(col) {
    for (let i = 0; i < col*col; i++) {
        const colDivs = document.createElement("div");
        colDivs.classList.add("box");
        containerGrid.appendChild(colDivs);
    }
}

makeGrid(16);   // make grid 16*16




/** generates a random hex colour
 *  @return {string} the color in the format `#rrggbb` */
function rainbowColor(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}




/* then we add behaviour */

// this is an htmlCollection (kind of like an array) of boxes
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

// change the colour when you click or mouseover a box
for (let box of boxes) {
    box.addEventListener("click", rainbowColor);
    box.addEventListener("mouseover", rainbowColor);
}




// clicking the reset button resets all the colours
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", () => {
    // set all to white
    for (let box of boxes) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
});
```

Here's a summary of the other fixes I also added:

#### general fixes

- renamed IDs, classes, and JS variables. some of them were confusing (like `col` was actually referring to individual boxes)

#### HTML fixes

- added the `type` attribute to the `<link>` tag
- no spaces before/after `=` in HTML
- `for` on `<labels>` should refer to the `id`, not `name`
- `value` for the colour `<input>` should not be `#rrggbb`. that's placeholder text. i set it to `#000000` because that's the hex code for black
- changed id/class names to hyphenated words instead of camelCase (the convention is to use hyphens for HTML/CSS, but camelCase for JS)

#### CSS fixes

- removed unused classes
- `grid-auto-rows` should be `grid-template-rows`
- `background-color: black` should have no quote marks

#### JS fixes

- changed `onclick` into event listeners
- put the listeners onto the `<button>`s instead of the `<div>`s containing them
- you were creating `<div>`s with JS where you could've just used HTML/CSS. in general, i only create elements with JS if (a) the elements need to be created dynamically (e.g. on click), or (b) it's more efficient to use JS (like creating the grid)
- when you call a function, no space goes between the function name and parentheses
- changed `randomColor()` to be more efficient using hex codes
- don't add the `col-row` ID inside the for-loop, since you're making multiple columns. no 2 elements should have the same ID!
- if you add a class to the columns inside the for-loop, why add the styling with JS? they already have the class, so just set the style with CSS
- changed the for-loop to actually use the `col` parameter you set in the function (instead of `16*16`)
- got rid of the `display: grid` on the individual boxes

Answer (score 1):

Move your for loops into the makeCols() because when you reset it removes all the divs along with their event listeners. Before you only assigned the events on page load. You need to assign the events anytime you make new divs.

```
function makeCols (col) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 16*16; i++) {
        const colDivs = document.createElement('div');
        colDivs.setAttribute('id', 'col-row');
        colDivs.classList.add('cols');
        colDivs.textContent ="";
        colDivs.style.border = ('solid');
        colDivs.style.display= ('grid');
        colDivs.style.padding = ('5px');
        containerGrid.appendChild(colDivs);
    }
    
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.cols');
    for(let k=0; k<inputs.length; k++) {
        inputs[k].onclick = rainbowColor;}
    let resets = document.querySelectorAll('.cols');
    for(let p=0; p<inputs.length; p++) {
            inputs[p].onmouseover = rainbowColor;
    }
}
makeCols (16);
```